# Spaces changed to "_" when returning result from procedure in c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I've database with stored procedure and DataGridView in my form.
I want to bind procedure result to DataGridView and everything work - table is being populated with result from procedure, but colums have underline ("_") instead spaces.
In example: "Cookies count" is shown as "Cookies_count".

Code in stored procedure setting column names:

  `SELECT    
 
   Films.TitlePL as [Polish title],
 
   Films.TitleOrg as [Original title],
 
   FilmCategory.CategoryName as [Category name], 
 
   Films.ProductionYear as [Year of production],`

C# code for run procedure with arguments and binding to DataGridView is here:

```
      var result = DB.spFilmFindSearchGridview(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

      List<spFilmFindSearchGridviewResult> Res = new List<spFilmFindSearchGridviewResult>();
      Res = result.ToList();

      DataGridViewFilmFind.DataSource = Res;
```

Comment: Can you verify by inspection that the values do or do not have the underscores in that actual list `Res`?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using EF or linq to sql? This must be a feature of that framework. Because spFilmFindSearchGridviewResult is a class it cannot have spaces in the property names so the framework must be adding the underscores.

EDIT: to fix this you should create the columns yourself and set AutoGenerateColumns to false

Comment: I don't have this property in DataGridView

Comment: @Aru looking at the DataGridView here I do see that property and it does show up in intellisense. Maybe you have an older version? One other option would just be to go through the columns collection and change the header to remove the underscore.